# PHP setcookie function not saving cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I was hoping someone might be able to help with this small issue I'm having with some code I'm working on. Please keep in mind, this is just for a hobby site, I am aware there are security holes.
I have written a function called set_remember_cookies that is called from my login script and registration page when the user checks the "remember me" box.

A function on each secured page then does the following:

1. Checks to see if the remember cookies are set
2. Queries the database to find the User_ID associated with the hashed username in the cookie
3. Gets the password for that User_ID from the user table
4. Gets the salt from the remember_cookies table
5. Hashes the password + salt and matches it against the hashed password in the cookie

Again, I know it is insecure to store even a hashed password in a cookie, but I am not worried about that now.

My problem is that the set_remember_cookies function, that I have included below, is not actually setting the cookies. On the secured pages, the first step (checking if the cookies exist) fails. I have also checked in the browser for the cookies, and they are not stored.

Can anyone explain to me why this function is not setting the cookies? I can't find any errors, but hopefully someone can! Thanks!

```
    <?php
      function set_remember_cookies($uid, $identifier, $password) {
          mysql_query("DELETE FROM remember_cookies WHERE User_ID = '$uid'"); //Delete old cookie records
          $salt = sha1(uniqid(time() . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
          $username_hash = hash("sha256", $identifier . $salt); //Hash the username
          if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO remember_cookies (User_ID, Username_Hash, Salt) VALUES ('$uid', '$username_hash', '$salt')")) {
              setcookie("Username", $username_hash, 60*60*24*365);
              setcookie("Password", hash("sha512", $password . $salt), 60*60*24*365);
          }
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your cookies expired sometime in 1971! Looks like you want an offset one year in the future, so try

```
 setcookie("Username", $username_hash, time() + 60*60*24*365);
```

The third parameter isn't an offset from 'now', it's an offset from the start of the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - the [rather fine manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) do make this clear :)

Comment: Well... I had a feeling I was overlooking something simple! I've used cookies before, and must have re-read those docs about 3 times today. Oh well, sometimes you need someone else to point something out I guess, lol! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[setcookie(name, $value, $expire)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php);

According to Manual: you need to add your expire time to time()

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
>   of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
>   this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
>   want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will
>   set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the
>   cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser
>   closes).